# Getting "Unsupported post request" error when creating Instagram ads campaign via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, facebook-business-sdk

I am trying to create a campaign for posting ads on Instagram using the Facebook Graph API. I am making the following curl request:

```
curl -X POST \
  -F 'name="My campaign"' \
  -F 'objective="OUTCOME_TRAFFIC"' \
  -F 'status="PAUSED"' \
  -F 'special_ad_categories=[]' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/campaigns
```

However, I am encountering the following error:
`{ "error": { "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", "type": "GraphMethodException", "code": 100, "error_subcode": 33, "fbtrace_id": "AKfpNdsOMgIw0dsAd9Cl" } }`

**What did you try?**

I have attempted the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Verified that the <ACCESS_TOKEN> is valid and has the necessary permissions for campaign creation.
2. Checked that the <AD_ACCOUNT_ID> is correctly replaced with the actual Facebook Ads Account ID.

**What were you expecting?**
I expected that the curl request to create a campaign on Instagram via the Facebook Graph API would be successful without any errors. Specifically, I anticipated that the campaign would be created with the provided parameters (name, objective, status, and special_ad_categories) and that I would receive a response confirming the successful creation of the campaign.